# How to set size for Media Recorder with notch display

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder to record the surface, So I'm defining the video size to the MediaRecorder before preparing

```
Size size = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
... preparing the media recorder
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(size.x, size.y);
```

So it is working fine without notch, when comes to the devices with notch the video is recorded as black.

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Shouldn't you be considering supported sizes for MediaRecorder using camera characteristics?

Answer (score 2):

Detect and subtract the notch height

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    Log.d("height",""+height);

    //Detect notch
    int statusBarHeight = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }

    if (statusBarHeight > Math.round( 24 * (displayMetrics.densityDpi / 160f))) {
        height -= statusBarHeight;
    }

    Log.d("height",""+height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the answer into 2 parts :

1. Using the API in Android 9 (API level 28).

   ```
   /**
    * Returns true if this WindowInsets has any nonzero insets.
    *
    * @return true if any inset values are nonzero
    */
   public boolean hasInsets() {
       return hasSystemWindowInsets() || hasWindowDecorInsets() || hasStableInsets()
               || mDisplayCutout != null;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the display cutout if there is one.
    *
    * @return the display cutout or null if there is none
    * @see DisplayCutout
    */
   @Nullable
   public DisplayCutout getDisplayCutout() {
       return mDisplayCutout;
   }
   ```

We use the API and get the displayCutout by applying setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
On our root view and save the sizes. You can also add required logic to make other adjustments should any is needed. 
Once we have the insets we can check if there is a cutout and we can calculate the sizes as needed. 
Also, you can set your activity to render as if there is no Notch/Cutout 
More info can be read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout#choose_how_your_app_handles_cutout_areas) .

2. Using an API provided by some of the OEMs (this case i show Huawei, I think a few more OEM have their own API but I'm not sure)
   The code below are 2 Context Extensions made in Kotlin allowing us to check if a notch exists and gets its size for further work.

   ```
   fun Context.hasNotchInScreenHuawei(): Boolean {
           var ret = false
           try {
               val cl = this.classLoader
               val hwNotchSizeUtil = cl.loadClass("com.huawei.android.util.HwNotchSizeUtil")
               val get = hwNotchSizeUtil.getMethod("hasNotchInScreen")
               ret = get.invoke(hwNotchSizeUtil) as Boolean
           } catch (ignored: Exception) {
           } finally {
               return ret
           }
       }

   fun Context.getNotchSizeHuawei(): IntArray {
       var ret = intArrayOf(0, 0)
       try {
           val cl = this.classLoader
           val hwNotchSizeUtil = cl.loadClass("com.huawei.android.util.HwNotchSizeUtil")
           val get = hwNotchSizeUtil.getMethod("getNotchSize")
           ret = get.invoke(hwNotchSizeUtil) as IntArray
       } catch (ignored: Exception) {
       } finally {
           return ret
       }
   }
   ```

You need to add a short meta-data to the Manifest under application as well.

```
    <meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true" />
```

This will allow the Huawei phone understand your app uses the added API by Huawei